# Changing object a Pointer points to, but the object wont change

Tags: c++

in my image class I want to change pixels after they're passed to the Image, and they should still change the picture.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  Image theImage(4, 8);//width/height
  Pixel aPixel(2,1);
  Pixel* p = &aPixel;
  theImage.setPixel(p);

  aPixel.setBlue(100);//change the blue (RGB) value of the pixel, but Pixel color doesnt change

  theImage.saveAsPixelMap("/Users/dan/Desktop/test.ppm");
  return 0;
}
```

I thought the color of the Pixel will change, because the Imageclass holds the pointer, when the pointer still points to the same Pixel, which Color is changed, shouldnt the Pixel`s Color in the Image change?

Here´s the Pixel constructor:

```
Pixel::Pixel(int tx, int ty){
  red = 255;
  green = 0;
  blue = 0;
  x = tx;
  y = ty;
  hasBeenChanged = false;
}
```

and the setPixel Method

```
void Image::setPixel(Pixel *aPixel){
  int tX = aPixel->getX();
  int tY = aPixel->getY();
  imageData.at(tY).at(tX)->setRed(aPixel->getRed());//value 0 - 255
  imageData.at(tY).at(tX)->setGreen(aPixel->getGreen());
  imageData.at(tY).at(tX)->setBlue(aPixel->getBlue());  
}
```

the imageData looks like this

```
std::vector< std::vector<Pixel*> > imageData;
```

and the saveAsPixelmap Method.

```
void Image::saveAsPixelMap(char aPath[]){

  std::ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open(aPath);

  myfile << "P3\n" << this->getWidth() <<" "<< this->getHeight() <<"\n255\n";
  std::vector < Pixel* > row;
  for (int y = 0; y < this->getHeight(); y++){
    row = imageData.at(y);
    for (int x = 0; x < this->getWidth(); x++){

        myfile << row.at(x)->getRed() << " ";
        myfile << row.at(x)->getGreen() << " ";
        myfile << row.at(x)->getBlue() << " ";
        std::cout <<"rot: "<< imageData.at(y).at(x)->getRed();

    }
  }
  std::cout << "\n Writing File to " << aPath << "\n \n";
  myfile.close();
}
```

ok, it´s a lot of code, please ask me if you require more information on something or my question is not clear enough. Any hints how to solve this much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept you implemented is different from what you describe:

- Described is, that something should change in the `Image`
- Implemented is pure copy semantics (read from the given pixel and put the values to some other pixel)

You need some kind of method of the `Image` class which returns a pixel - which than can be changed.

Example:

```
class Image { 
// ..
Pixel & get_pixel(int x, int y) { /* */ }
}
```

Then you can change the pixel (afterwards) with:

```
image.get_pixel(2,1).setBlue(100)
```

Comment: ah sure how silly I only change the color of the existing Pixels and dont pass in a new created Pixel. I think I have to change a bit more yes.

Comment: I changed the setPixel method and removed the copy semantics. Thanks for the hint. I will also think if the get_pixel can be useful in future, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The `setPixel` method should take a reference to a pointer:

```
void Image::setPixel(Pixel *& aPixel) { .. }
```

Comment: Quick Spot! Most of the times people get pass by reference wrong in C++. +1

Comment: It sadly didnt work, but the next poster showed me I did something wrong yes.

Comment: Image::setPixel does not change the value of the pointer.  There is no advantage in or need to pass a reference.

Comment: Um... why? The method doesn't change the pointer. (Actually it doesn't change the object the pointer points to, so I think it should be `(const Pixel * aPixel)`.)